# Android: Can we detected if a permission has been disabled on App Ops?

Tags: android, permissions, android-app-ops

With Android 4.3 we have a hidden Intent of the OS - App Ops - that allows us to disable some of the permissions of the installed apps (that's great!).

But as an app developer i'm trying to find out if **there is a way to check if the permission has been disabled** to warn the user to enable it to have access to the feature again, or something like that.

If there is, how?

Note: In case you are asking yourselves what I'm talking about:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appaholics.applauncher

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882316/what-happens-when-permission-is-disabled-with-os-4-3s-new-feature/17889167

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found that a similiar question had been asked and answered:

> At present, I know of no direct way to determine if you have been
>   blocked by App Ops. - [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17889167/327011)

More info: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/26/app-ops-developer-faq.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. It will really gonna help me in future. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps :

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.checkPermission(permission.FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Check below links for more help :

[How permission can be checked at runtime without throwing SecurityException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception)

[Is there a way to check for manifest permission from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292558/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-manifest-permission-from-code)